# Using Google API v3 - administrative_area_level_2 tag

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm using HTML to display a map area with a number of points/markers in it.

I use this function to 'pan' / move the map to see a specific place (list of places on the side of my web page).

```
    function animate(lati,long) {
     var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long); //Makes a latlng
     map.panTo(latLng); //Make map global
    }
```

QUERY :-  I've found in this website, a Google tag called "administrative_area_level_2"

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

From what i gather - this tag tells Google maps / API services to display the COUNTY area / borders (in USA at least & other countries).

However, when looking at maps.google.com & finding  a USA county - the HTML source code is so confusing / jumbled.

Has anyone used this administrative_area_level_2 tag before to show a county border ? & are there any tutorials / examples of how to use it ?

Or is this tag something completely different ?

(Some of my markers are counties - but others are towns / cities).

Answer (score 0):

*From what i gather - this tag tells Google maps / API services to display the COUNTY area / borders (in USA at least & other countries)*

This "tag" tells Google maps when used inside a request, that the response should be filtered to this component.

When returned within the response it tells you the type of the component .

This "tag" will not have any effect to the drawing of the map, and currently there isn't any implemented option to automatically draw any borders .